# Use DataFrame to add values until certain amount, then store the remainder in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating an inventory management system in python.

The goal is to make sure any given order weighs less than 1800g. If it's heavier than 1800g, split the order into multiple shipments.

So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd

product_info = [{"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC A+ Adult", "product_id": 0}, {"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC B+ Adult", "product_id": 1}, {"mass_g": 750, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Adult", "product_id": 2}, {"mass_g": 680, "product_name": "RBC O- Adult", "product_id": 3}, {"mass_g": 350, "product_name": "RBC A+ Child", "product_id": 4}, {"mass_g": 200, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Child", "product_id": 5}, {"mass_g": 120, "product_name": "PLT AB+", "product_id": 6}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "PLT O+", "product_id": 7}, {"mass_g": 40, "product_name": "CRYO A+", "product_id": 8}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "CRYO AB+", "product_id": 9}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP A+", "product_id": 10}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP B+", "product_id": 11}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP AB+", "product_id": 12}]
order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 10, "quantity": 4}]}

def check_weight(order, product_info):
    product_info_df = pd.DataFrame(product_info).set_index("product_id")
    order_df = pd.DataFrame(order["requested"]).set_index("product_id")
    order_weight = order_df.join(product_info_df)[['quantity', 'mass_g']].prod(1).sum()
    if order_weight > 1800:
        #???
    else:
        print('product shipped!')
```

If the weight is over 1800g, I'd like to split the order. 
That is, take the items with less than 1800g total weight and subtract their quantities from `order`,  then run that through the code again (and again) until all quantities of `order` are 0, and thus, the order would be 100% fulfilled.


How would I write that logic?

Comment: please post an expected output dataframe for that logic

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is, firstly have a counter for total number of orders. Then if weight>1800, subtract one from that total number. Subtract one from your else statement too so the total changes here as well. Make a while loop so that this code runs until total goes to 0. Let me know if that makes sense or if you have any follow up questions.